# parcel unable to bind to $PORT heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, parceljs

I have built an app using parcel bundler and I am trying to deploy to heroku but getting the error below,  believe this is because parcel uses 1234 as the default port and heroku will try to use a random port, is there a way to override this?

`2018-10-21T13:10:13.750160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

How can I deploy my parcel bundled app on heroku?

Comment: Are you using `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000)` or something like this?

Comment: I'm not sure where this would go in parcel as most of the config is done automatically by parcel

Comment: I mean node.js code. You have to listen to the port in your node.js app

Comment: it's a react app built with parcel, if it was built using webpack I presume this goes in the webpack config

Comment: @tomharrison, React is a front-end web framework. It sholdn't be binding to _anything_ since it runs in the user's browser, not on the server. Is there a back-end component, possibly built using Node.js?

Comment: yes react is not serving the app, parcel is as far as I'm aware and this is where I would have thought the config needs to be changed

Comment: (Also, Parcel doesn't bind to anything. _Your code_ does. Parcel would make the variable available to your code.)

Comment: I don't think Parcel is serving the app. Can you please [edit] your question and show us your main back-end code file?

Comment: parcel is serving the app my package.json has -  "start":" parcel index.html", and serves the app on default port of 1234

Comment: @tomharrison, Parcel isn't a web server. It's a build tool. Again, do you have a back-end component? Something that might provide an API for your React client to talk to?

Comment: I've found an issue on parcel's github https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/1126 , parcel has a devserver , maybe I need something else to run this in production but Im just trying to view in development on heroku like I can on my local

Comment: @tomharrison, if you don't have any back-end code you don't really need Heroku (though I think you can use it if you want to). You just need a static web server, which is much simpler. And you'd bundle your application into (probably) a single JavaScript file, which you'd host as a regular file, and you'd have an `index.html` file that pulls the JS in.